# Is a C# struct ever boxed when declared as the return value of a function?

Tags: c#, struct, return-value, boxing, value-type

A simple question, but I haven't found a definitive answer on Stack Overflow.

```
    struct MyStruct { int x, y, z; }

    MyStruct GetMyStruct() => new MyStruct();

    static void Main()
    {
        var x = GetMyStruct();      // can boxing/unboxing ever occur?
    }
```

Is a **C#** struct (value type) *always* copied to the stack when returned from a function, no matter how large it might be? The reason I'm unsure is that for some instruction sets other than MSIL (such as x86), a return value usually needs to fit into a processor register, and the stack is not directly involved.

If so, is it the call site that pre-allocates space on the CLR stack for the (expected) value return type?

---

**[edit: Summary of replies]**
 For the intent of the original question, the answer is ***no***; the CLR will never (silently) box a `struct` just for the purpose of transferring it as a return value.

Comment: If a return of a value type is ever (your use of 'ever' seem to imply that sometimes if it happens, it's not unconditional) boxed, it'll mean there's implicit unboxing when we assign the return to a value type variable, and that seems inefficient. I don't know pretty much anything about MSIL and CLR so I can't help you here. Anyway, may I know what prompted your question?

Comment: @blizpasta: my original question was actually rendered moot when I realized I was incorrectly thinking that the 'ref' (and 'out') keywords caused boxing of value types (which is not the case). Wanting to avoid that, I was going to 'return' the structs. But once I remembered that 'ref' doesn't box value types, using an out parameter became an option. The size of my value type is currently 4+IntPtr.Size bytes, and hundreds of thousands of these structs are very intensively manipulated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a heavy implementation detail of the JIT compiler.  In general, if the struct is small enough and has simple members then its gets returned in CPU registers.  If it gets too big then the calling code reserves enough space on the stack and passes a pointer to that space as an extra hidden argument.

It will never be boxed, unless the return type of the method is *object* of course.

Fwiw: this is also the reason that the debugger cannot display the return value of the function in the Autos window.  Painful sometimes.  But the debugger doesn't get enough metadata from the JIT compiler to know exactly where to find the value.  Edit: fixed in VS2013.

Answer (score 6):

A struct is boxed whenever you want to treat it as an `object`, so if you call `Func` and assign the result to object it will be boxed.

E.g. doing this

```
 object o = Func();
```

will yield the following IL

```
L_0000: call valuetype TestApp.foo TestApp.Program::Func()
L_0005: box TestApp.foo
L_000a: stloc.0
```

which shows that the return value is boxed, because we assign it to a reference of the type `object`.

If you assign it to a variable of type `Foo` it isn't boxed and thus it is copied and the value is stored on the stack.

Also, boxing wouldn't really help you here since it would involve creating an object to represent the value of the struct, and the values are effectively copied during the boxing operation.

Comment: The fact that the call site must allocate the appropriate number of bytes on the stack is the reason why the .NET design guidelines suggest that `struct`s should ideally be no bigger than 16 bytes.

Comment: @Richard: Do you have a source for that info?

Comment: Yes, that contains the 16 byte recommendation, but doesn't say it's because the call site has to allocate data.

Comment: I'll try to track down the specific source where I read this.

Comment: @JimMischel based on the answers, if you want to guarantee and ensure the avoidance of bltting large structs, you should explicitly use `ref` or `out` instead of **return**ing the struct.

Comment: @RichardCook The reason people want to know is probably that the logic doesn't necessarily follow; given a 1000 byte struct, it's perfectly efficient for the caller to allocate space for it in its own frame and have a callee "fill it in," if we assume that the entire result is then examined/consumed/processed ***in-situ*** by the caller. That is, such a design guideline entails a further assumption that the caller is incapable of, or blithe to, being careful not to ***subsequently*** "lift" jumbo structs out of place, which would indeed be a real problem.