# How C# returns Structs

Tags: c#, class, struct, clr, return-value

Structs are value types and thus are fully copied every time there is a manipulation on the struct. Since they are value types, structs are allocated in the stack and not in the heap.

I can see how structs can degrade the performance of methods when structs are passed as parameters, since they will be always copied in the stack, specially if they are big with lots of inner fields.

But I am curious about how C# deals with the return of structs.

In C the return is made by registers, or by reference using the heap if the value to be returned is too big for the registers. And practically all C# struct tutorials say structs lives in the stack, never in the heap.

So in the following code:

```
MyStruct ms = GetMyValue();
```

Where `GetMyValue()` is

```
MyStruct GetMyValue();
```

How will C# deal with the return of the  struct for the ms variable? Specially if it's is too big for the registers? Will it in fact copy it to the heap and then copy it back again to the caller of the method and assign it to ms?

---

**EDIT:**

To address the comments left in the post:

1. I have read a few tutorial on C# structs before posting this, [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/struct) in particular uses the word `stack` more times than I bother to count. And [this MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) also speaks about the stack, although it's from 2003, I don't think structs changed since then.
2. I am aware this might not be realted at all with C# but in fact be a matter of the JIT compiler it self or the CLR or something else I am not aware of. That's the purpose of my question, to learn more about the inner workings of C#, even if this is not actually related to the language itself.
3. There are C function call conventions, the best support for my Post is [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784820/how-can-eax-store-return-value-of-which-size-is-bigger-than-4-bytes). When I first posted it in here I just said what I remembered, but since the SO answer says:

   > As for your specific question, it depends the ABI. Sometimes if the return value is larger than 4 bytes but not larger than 8 bytes, it can be split into EAX and EDX. But most of the time the calling function will just allocate some memory **(usually on the stack)** and pass a pointer to this area to the called function.

   I might be wrong on this one, and I say *might*, because the answer says *usually*.
4. The true reason why I want to understand how structs are handled is because I have a project where I have to read a Serial Port multiple times to poll for data, this data will be returned by a method.

   Since the data is just some bytes I thought I could get some performance out of structs instead of using a class to abstract the bytes incoming by the Serial Port, but if the `return` would pass the `struct` as a heap allocation my expectations on performance increase could be false.

   **Yes, I can make a simple test and compare performance**, I know, but I wanted to actually **learn** how it's done behind the curtains, and not only memorize the outcome of my simulation. I like to know how the things that I work with actually work, and not only learn how to use them.

Comment: `And practically all C# struct tutorials say structs lives in the stack, never in the heap.` They don't all say that.  Any that do are strictly wrong.   `In C the return is made by registers, or by reference using the heap` No, the heap is never used to` pass the return value to the caller.

Comment: It might be a tad cheaper, but a value type is always copied for a return. To use structs efficiently, you need to use ref/out parameters. Protip: Use class. If unsure, benchmark a struct. Costs almost no time.

Comment: In the code MyStruct ms = GetMyValue(), 'ms' has a memory footprint whether on the heap or the stack. The return of GetMyValue() is simply copied into that location where 'ms' resides.

Comment: *"Structs are value types and thus are fully copied every time there is a manipulation on the struct."* Thats not true, mutable structs are not copied every time they are manipulated, only when they are passed.

Comment: I dont understand the point of down vote. When some one is trying to learn something thats all you can do? Even if he is wrong in many parts you should not downvote. Im not saying i know this. Im learning too but it would be good to tell the reason of downvote.

Comment: C# does not handle or return structs at all, it leaves that to the CLR.

Comment: Not an exact dupe but the answers on this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3742922/60761) will clear you up.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - the question propagates a few false ideas about structs in C#. And I'm not so sure about the C 'facts' either.

Comment: Almost every sentence in this question is false. It's difficult to answer a question that is predicated on so many falsehoods.

Comment: I edited the original post to back some of the things I said, this way you can see where I got my ideas from.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks a lot, I think I got the answer I wanted by your link, which is to understand how the struct is moved back and forth in memory when there is a method call returning a struct.

Comment: @EricLippert I am sorry to hear it, I just spoke my understandings of the topic after reading about structs on several websites.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It's not the falsehoods in the question, it's the lack of research.  This is a very well documented subject with lots of readily available information out there.  It's also excessively broad.

Comment: @Servy kind to give me one? On how the struct is handled in memory and returned to the caller function?

Comment: @mFeinstein Google can give you a few thousand, all you have to do is ask.

Comment: @Servy I did, and all I get is "struct are value types....they live in the stack....careful when calling methods passing structs as parameters", but nothing on what happens when the return of a method is a struct.

Comment: @mFeinstein Neither of the sources you cited in your question stated that.  In fact, both explicitly contradict your statement that all structs live on the stack.  Of course, if you're having trouble understand that first source you looked at, look at some more. You have a lot to choose from.

Comment: @Servy I read multiple tutorials, I didn't posted all of them in here. The "careful when calling methods passing structs as parameters" is because of the value type characteristic of strucs since they will be copied back and forth all the time and this can degrade performance and I think I read it in another source.

Comment: @mFeinstein Yes, structs are copied when passed to or returned from methods.  This can cause performance problems if they're used improperly.  That not at all what you stated in your question, or even in your previous comment.

Comment: @Servy I know, I didn't ask about passing structs, my question was about returning strucs, how it's handled so I can understand the performance impacts of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value types are not only located on a stack. They also live in fields and in arrays. The key distinction to reference types is that value types are copied by value and have no identity. The stack vs. heap idea is false.

> In C the return is made by registers, or by reference using the heap if the value to be returned is too big for the registers

The heap is not involved. The caller allocates spaces for the return value to be placed in. It passes a pointer to that space. The callee can fill that space. The .NET CLR does this as well. Of course this is an implementation detail.

> but I wanted to actually learn

This is very good. You could not have tested what I just told you. You need to be a little more critical in what you believe what others say. Either you had bad tutorials or you read them in an imprecise way.

> I can see how structs can degrade the performance of methods when structs are passed as parameters, since they will be always copied in the stack

This is not always the case I think. I'm not quite sure but I think the JIT can sometimes pass structs in registers. The .NET JITs really do not optimize much but I think this is an optimization that works to a certain degree. Probably driven by the existence of some one-field structs such as `DateTime`.

Comment: Yes, based on the link posted in the comments, it appears that the JIT can optimize the return depending on the stuct size. Thank you for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

structs do not always live on the stack. if you allocate a struct inside of a function, it lives its life on the stack. if it's a field of a reference type(class/array(implicitly derived from System.Array/Object), it lives its life on the heap. as far as how theyre returned, that might be up to the ABI for that CPU architecture.

from the sounds of it, you've never dealt with IL/assembly/code generation, so lets build a dynamic method thats equivalent to MyStruct ms = GetMyValue()/what the compiler would generate in context of the word stack. "things" are never actually returned. thing(s, in a tuple sense i'm sure), are pushed onto the stack, and then a return instruction is emitted. leaving the return value(s) for the caller. we're going to assume GetMyValue() allocates a new MyStruct and assigns it to a local variable. the generated code would look something like this(i extend the ILGenerator class):

```
ILGenerator generator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();

generator
    .DeclareLocal(typeof(MyStruct))
    .EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(EncapsulatingClass).GetMethod("GetMyValue"))
    .Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, 0);
```

what happens here is(some of this is my assumption on how the CLI runtime works):

1. the calling function reserves a slot of typeof(MyStruct) at the current local list index.
2. GetMyValue() is called, reserves a MyStruct local the same way the method we are building does, emits an OpCodes.Newobj, which allocates and adjusts ESP(extended stack pointer) downward in the amount of sizeof(MyStruct), emits OpCodes.Stloc to store ESP minus sizeof(MyStruct) into the reserved local index, does some stuff with its fields, calls Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, 0) to push the address the local points to onto the evaluation stack for the calling function, and emits an OpCodes.Ret to return.
3. the calling function emits an OpCodes.Stloc to store(copy) the contents of the MyStruct the top of the evaluation stack points to(how this happens, well i'm sure the answer is it depends, unfortunately), at local index 0.

i'm not an expert on how the CLI runtime is constructed by any means, so a lot of this is an assumption of what happens. take it with a grain of salt, and i'm by no means a CPU engineering expert. how the instruction stream segment of OpCodes.Ldloc, OpCodes.Ret, OpCodes.Stloc -- ms = GetMyValue() -- is treated, is probably up to how the JITer translates the IL into actual cpu specific machine instructions. such as X86. what determines if a struct will be returned into a register, is probably limited to one register only, so whatever the biggest register is, and if whatever struct will fit inside of it. i know CPU's can combine registers for memory offsets, but i'm not sure if that applies to returning structs inside of multiple registers. another thing to keep in mind, GetMyValue() went out of scope, which means the struct GetMyValue() allocated, in a scope sense, doesn't exist anymore, but in a stack sense(where it was allocated), it does, so the JITer could very well have just taken the address OpCodes.Ldloc pushed onto the stack, and placed it directly into the callers local index 0. since nothing can possibly copy it anymore due to the function returning. making the caller the new owner of the struct. avoiding any copying and registers altogether in this special case. this might be where calling conventions come into play as well. the problem is, if you allocated three structs in GetMyValue() for whatever reason, returning any struct after the first struct allocated would break that optimization, which is where the next optimization, return the struct inside a register(if it fits), comes into play. leaving the worst case scenario, copying its contents purely onto the stack again for the caller. i could be wrong, and anyone is more than welcome to chime in and correct me. a good place to start, would be github and see how the runtime handles OpCodes.Ldloc/Stloc for structs. i would imagine that's a good spot to look when it comes to getting the answers you need.

EDIT: any tutorial you've read that says structs are always allocated on the stack, have them all DDoS'd.

Comment: "if you allocate a struct inside of a function, it lives its life on the stack" - not if it is an async method, or an iterator block, etc; even this is an over-simplification that is factually wrong

Comment: if it's allocated inside an async method, then that's part of "inside of a reference type." i think most people understand the TPL internals/Task queueing. I guess that's not right to say if he doesn't.

Comment: It is more complex than that, even; the state machine constructed is, at least in release builds, a value type. Whether it ends up on the heap depends on whether it ever hits an incomplete continuation. Really nuanced.

Comment: And we could cover other edge cases like "captured variables" - so many "except"s!