# How can I prevent a copy when returning a new struct?

Tags: c#, optimization, struct

I have a struct, which is used in a transient manner, that looks something like this:

```
internal readonly struct TrackingId
{
    public readonly string Source1;
    public readonly string Source2;
    public readonly string SourceN;

    // Computed from Source1..N
    public readonly string Value; 

    private TrackingId(string source1, string source2, string sourceN)
    {
        Source1 = source1;
        Source2 = source2;
        SourceN = sourceN;

        Value = String.Join("-", Source1, Source2, SourceN);
    }

    public static TrackingId Create(string source1, string source2, string sourceN)
    {
        return new TrackingId(source1, source2, sourceN);
    }
}
```

The actual type has many fields, so performing a copy is very undesirable behavior. However, my understanding is that the runtime will copy the new instance to the caller unless/until it decides to inline the `Create` method, which there's no guarantee will happen.

I'm essentially looking for something similar to C++'s copy elision, in which the returned object is constructed in-place in the caller's storage; is there any way for me reliably prevent the `Create` method from performing a copy?

Comment: Can you describe the use case a little clearer? I’m not sure exactly what it is you’re trying to do, and why won’t a class work?

Comment: Is having `Create` use an `out TrackingId` parameter rather than a return an option?

Comment: @theMayer My application creates an incredibly high number of local `TrackingId` instances, each with a very short lifetime. Heap allocation is an issue.

Comment: @PhilM Possibly as a last resort, but it incurs significant readability issues with the code that's using it. Being able to elide the copy would be ideal (and seems like something that *should* be possible)

Comment: Perhaps Ref Return Values? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft My understanding is that it requires the return value to have a lifetime that exceeds the method, so local variables can't be used with it.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3742922/4934172) might be related.

Comment: Can you implement a list-bases approach? Build a list, extend that struct with a method  `Create(IEnumerable<string> sources)` and also add another constructor which consumes that list?

Comment: @Ramtec This is heavily simplified, in the real code there are a number of combinations of sources that it can be constructed from (and multiple `Create` methods).

Comment: In reading the comments, I can't help but think you probably need to rethink the design of this a bit. (a) consider streaming/observables of some sort and (b) consider breaking it down into simpler components. Complexity is the enemy of reliability.

Comment: "Heap allocation is an issue." - not here it isn't; a struct return value is not passed on the heap. The only relevant factor is copy (blit) overhead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you already know the answer here. With the constraints you have identified, there is no way to achieve what you want.

The only ways you would be able to do this is by using a `ref return`. Yet you can't *return* the *reference* of a *value-type* that is created locally. Hence you can't mitigate the *defensive copy*.

You have also ruled out using the `ref`/`in`/`out` modifiers, these would also mitigate the *defensive copy*.

So, you are stuck and cannot achieve what you want.

- You will have to ditch the `Create` type methods if you don't want a *copy*
- Or you will have to start using the language features that allow passing *structs* by *reference*, by using *readonly* and/or `in`/`ref`/`out` modifiers, or using `ref return` with a *non-local* types.

In short, you will need to refactor your workflows to cater for copy-free code.